# Pandas time series data Index from a string to float

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Would anyone know how to convert the string output to a float? What I am attempting to do create separate data frames for `"Month"` and `"day of the week"` based on the time stamp index. The `df.index.strftime` outputs a string but I need a `float` based on the months numerical value (0-11 or 1-12 for a Jan thru December) and a day of the week numerical value (0-6 or 1-7 for Sunday thru Saturday)

```
from numpy.random import randint
import pandas as pd

# Create a df with a date-time index with data every 6 hours
rng = pd.date_range('1/5/2018 00:00', periods=5, freq='6H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Random_Number':randint(1, 10, 5)}, index=rng)

# Getting different time information in the columns

df['month'] = df.index.strftime('%b')
df['Day_of_week'] = df.index.strftime('%a')

df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`DatetimeIndex.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month.html) and [`DatetimeIndex.dayofweek`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html):

```
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['Day_of_week'] = df.index.dayofweek
print (df)
                     Random_Number  month  Day_of_week
2018-01-05 00:00:00              1      1            4
2018-01-05 06:00:00              8      1            4
2018-01-05 12:00:00              4      1            4
2018-01-05 18:00:00              5      1            4
2018-01-06 00:00:00              1      1            5
```